# how to interpret reading decision tree result from ctree() in r?

Tags: r, modeling, cart

After running ctree(model)

My result look like this below :

```
1) iv == (a,b,c) ; criterion = 1 , statistic = 200 
    2) iv2 == (x,y) ; criterion = 0.99 , statistic = 32 
        3) iv3 < 30 ; criterion = 0.91 , statistic = 35 
            4) weight = 100
```

I am new to this , but can anyone please explain to me say my total volume is 500

I know that that node (4 ) given me volume of 100 , but what exactly is criterion = 1 and statistic = 200 means ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree is recursively partitioning by testing for independence between the input variables and the response.

Criterion is 1 - p-value. The tree will split as long as criterion is above some minimum that you can set.

Statistic is the test statistic, which can also vary.